# How to index match a condition set in a cell

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, match, lookup-tables

I am trying to avoid having a multiple if formula by index matching a table instead, however what i need to match is the actual condition and a string.

**Lookup table:**

```
+---+------------------+-------------------+-------+
|   |        A         |         B         |   C   |
+---+------------------+-------------------+-------+
| 1 | Current to Prior | Portfolio Comment | Error |
| 2 | =0               | ""                | 1     |
| 3 | <>0              | ""                | -1    |
| 4 | >0               | OK – Losses       | 0     |
| 5 | <0               | OK – Losses       | 1     |
| 6 | <0               | OK – New Sales    | 0     |
| 7 | >0               | OK – New Sales    | 1     |
+---+------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

- Column A: Lookup Condition
- Column B: Lookup string
- Column C: Return value

**Data example with correct hard coded output (column C):**

```
+---+------------------+-------------------+-------+
|   |        A         |         B         |   C   |
+---+------------------+-------------------+-------+
| 1 | Current to Prior | Portfolio comment | Error |
| 2 | 0                |                   | 1     |
| 3 | -100             | OK – Losses       | 1     |
| 4 | 50               |                   | -1    |
| 5 | 200              | OK – Losses       | 0     |
| 6 | 0                |                   | 1     |
| 7 | -400             | OK – New Sales    | 0     |
| 8 | 0                |                   | 1     |
+---+------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

- Column A: Data value
- Column B: Data string
- Column C: Output formula

I need a formula that matches the data value with the lookup condition, the data string with the lookup string and outputs the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you weren't necessarily asking for a VBA solution, but myself (and many others) prefer using UDFs as, in my opinion, it makes reading formulas easier and cleaner - plus you can do without the helper cells.

We start off your UDF by creating a Select Case Statement. We could choose to use either the Numerical Value or String for the cases. I decided to go with the string.

Within each case, you will compare the numerical values provided to the `lngCondition` parameter, which will ultimately return the value to the function.

Since you didn't have any cases for when textual values could have a `lngCondition = 0`, I made it return a worksheet error code `#VALUE`, just as you'd expect from any other Excel formula. This is the reason for the UDF having a variant return type.

```vb
Public Function ReturnErrorCode(lngCondition As Long, strComment As String) As Variant

    Select Case strComment
    Case ""
        If lngCondition = 0 Then
            ReturnErrorCode = 1
        Else
            ReturnErrorCode = -1
        End If

    Case "OK - Losses"
        If lngCondition > 0 Then
            ReturnErrorCode = 0
        ElseIf lngCondition < 0 Then
            ReturnErrorCode = 1
        Else
            ' Your conditions don't specify that 'OK - Losses'
            '     can have a 0 value
            ReturnErrorCode = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        End If

    Case "OK - New Sales"
        If lngCondition < 0 Then
            ReturnErrorCode = 0
        ElseIf lngCondition > 0 Then
            ReturnErrorCode = 1
        Else
            ' Your conditions don't specify that 'OK - New Sales'
            '     can have a 0 value
            ReturnErrorCode = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        End If

    Case Else
        ReturnErrorCode = CVErr(xlErrValue)

    End Select

End Function
```

You would then use this formula in the worksheet as such:

```
=ReturnErrorCode(A1, B1)
```

[image]

---

> *Great! But I have no knowledge of VBA and don't know how to add a UDF.*

- First, you need to open the VBA Editor. You can do this by simultaneously pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.
- Next, you need to create a standard code module. In the VBE, click **Insert** then select **Module** *(NOT Class module!)*.
- Then copy the code above, and paste it into the new code module you just created.
- Since you have now added VBA code to your workbook, you now need to save it as a **macro-enabled workbook** the next time you save.

Comment: Helpful, and solves my issue perfectly. out of curiosity, is it possible to do it by excel defined formula?

Comment: _Is it possible to do by a normal worksheet formula?_ Absolutely, but that's out of my league. I am pretty proficient with VBA, but not so much with worksheet formulas. There are many here who can work magic with Excel formulas though

Comment: And if you are still wanting that type of solution, I would recommend that you unmark my answer as your accepted answer. This lets others know you are still looking for an alternate solution. You won’t hurt my feelings :-)